# not Getting current URL

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add a product to `cart` by using url

```
/cart/addtocart?projectId=11480904060&quantity=1
```

after this the product will be added to cart by

```
/cart/shippingcart
```

url. I want to show destination url in `omniture` in firebug.

problem is it is taking

```
/cart/addtocart?projectId=11480904060&quantity=1
```

as destination url istead of

```
/cart/shippingcart
```

I tried

```
digitalData['page']['pageInfo']['destinationURL'] = document.URL;
```

**Problem:**

this code in tracking omniture but it is failing the specs of `jasmine`

Comment: qsn looks confusing to me, can you post some code to explain it

Comment: OKay, so what have you got in it? Why JavaScript and RoR?

Comment: I don't have this specifically, but I can write about a shopping cart I have implemented if you'd benefit from that

Comment: If you are using DTM then it is very easy to get the URL with the help of Data Element.The question seems to be incomplete and sorry but ROR+JS confuse me.